# how can i add c program in android text view

Tags: android

i am creating "C" app for students, now i want to add c text file to display on android app but its showing some errors, how can add large program in text view or is there any other way to write the code....(it showing error as too many parameters in textview...).please help me out this problem...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:minWidth="310dp"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"



    android:text="



    #include<stdio.h>
                #include<math.h>
                void main() 
                {
printf("hello world");
              }
         "/>


     </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add the string in strings.xml and try again.In this code you are missing double quotes for  android:text .

Comment: and you forgot to close the ending bracket of the TextView [/>]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to save your C program in asset folder and load it from there using File system and then use `WebView` instead of `Textview`, it will be easy

```
private String readFileInAssetsDir(String filename) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(filename)));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line + "\n");
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

then you can show it in `webview` like this way

```
String plainCd = readFileInAssetsDir("code.c");
String htmlCd = "<pre>" + plainCd + "</pre>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlCd , "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"



    android:text="
    #include&lt;stdio.h&gt;
                #include&lt;math.h&gt;
                void main()
                {
printf(&#8220;hello world&#8221;);
              }
         "/>
```